# Рендер вьюхи из одного контролера в другой

Tags: ruby-on-rails

У меня есть контроллеры `home`, с вьюхой `index`, и `users`, с вьюхой `new`. Как мне поместить данные из вьюхи `new` в `index`, чтобы переменные контроллера `users` там работали?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Answer (score 1):

Каждая вьюха берёт данные из соответствующего экшена своего контроллера. Поэтому, если вы ходите работать с юзером в home#index, то определите для этого переменную в методе index контроллера home. Можно и несколько переменных, для разных действий, например так:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.new #Объект, для нового пользователя.
    @users = User.all #Список всех пользователей, если вы заходите вывести их в той же вьюхе.
  end
```

Этот способ соответствует структуре приложений Rails, потому лучше не изгаляться, а использовать его. Иначе половину действий, которые Рельсы могли сделать за вас, вам придётся реализовывать самому.

Answer (score 0):

какая именно задача стоит? вы хотите что бы регистрация была на главной странице? тогда просто в роут файле укажите root 'user#new', или вы хотите что бы главной была именно home#index и помимо регистрации там должно быть ещё что то? тогда можно просто скопировать вьюху user#new и заменить <%= form_for [@user](/users/36/user) do |f| %> на <%= form_for User.new do |f| %>, либо в контроллер home в метод index скопировать содержимое метода new контроллера user, тогда заменять ничего не надо

Comment: а если нужно много где применять метод из контроллера, тогда его лучше реализовать в хелпере

Comment: Ни в коем случае, не form_for User.new do |f|, только form_for @user do |f|, а @user определить в контроллере. Во вьюхе не должно быть ничего, кроме вывода, таково соглашение. Все запросы к БД и обработку данных берёт на себя контроллер.

Comment: я написал, что можно так, а можно и в контроллере, можно ещё в хелпере

Comment: "либо в контроллер home в метод index скопировать содержимое метода new контроллера user" - это разве не то, что вы уже после меня написали?

Comment: @stepofchange, суть в том, что верен только второй вариант. Вся суть простоты Rails в соблюдении соглашения об именовании и структуры приложения. Чем больше подобных вольностей вы допускаете в своём коде, тем он сложнее для понимания, и тем больше дополнительного кода придётся писать. То, что нормально для программирования на "чистом" языке, может быть грубой ошибкой для разработки с помощью фреймворка. Самого это бесило, пока не освоился.